# Highlight corresponding list items in other lists on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three unordered lists each containing a subset of a group of items with repeating entries between the lists. I'd like to highlight the matching items in all of the lists when hovering over any instance of that item. So if ITEM-A is included in lists 1 & 3, when I hover over ITEM-A in list 1 or 3, I'd like both instances of the item to be assigned a class from which I can then style it. Think Google Translate but for identical items as opposed to translated strings. In order to attach CSS classes to matching items I am programmatically replicating the content of the list item in the title attribute (I have to do it this way as the content is made available and required in multiple languages), I am hoping I can use the jquery/CSS attribute selectors as a way of making the match.

The code would look like this:

```
<ul class="tags">
   <li title="ITEM-C">ITEM-C</li>
   <li title="ITEM-D">ITEM-D</li>
   <li title="ITEM-F">ITEM-F</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tags">
   <li title="ITEM-A">ITEM-A</li>
   <li title="ITEM-C">ITEM-C</li>
   <li title="ITEM-D">ITEM-D</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tags">
   <li title="ITEM-D">ITEM-D</li>
   <li title="ITEM-F">ITEM-F</li>
   <li title="ITEM-G">ITEM-G</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $("li[title='" + this.title + "']").addClass('yourClass');
}, function() {
    $("li[title='" + this.title + "']").removeClass('yourClass');
});
```

you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mamoo/HFUj3/)

Comment: `$(this).attr("title")` == `this.title`. ;-) Also, this will break for titles that contain single quotes and probably for those with square brackets as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = {};

$("ul.tags li")
.each(function () {
    if ( !(this.title in index) ) {
        index[this.title] = $();
    }
    index[this.title].push(this);
})
.hover(
    function () {
        index[this.title].addClass("highlight");
    },
    function () {
        index[this.title].removeClass("highlight");
    }
);
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/4cLvB/